# Hyperlink in textview not showing link around text in Android

Tags: android, textview

I want to show link for text in textview for address i enter in anchor tag android. I tried following code till now with output.

Textview XML layout:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Textview java code:

```
    private String tweet="&lt;a href=http://www.google.co.in&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;";
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
    test.setText(Html.fromHtml(tweet));
test.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

[image: Output]

It should show only Google and on clicking that it should open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The String `tweet` must contain real `HTML` code, not escaped tags. Additionally, it is better to surround attributes with quotes: (Need to be escaped)

So this line:

```
private String tweet="&lt;a href=http://www.google.co.in&gt;Google&lt;/a&gt;";
```

has to be changed to this:

```
private String tweet="<a href=\"http://www.google.co.in\">Google</a>";
```

You also need to remove `android:autoLink="web"` and `android:linksClickable="true"`:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
```

Comment: tried with this also doesnt work.. shows only google but no link

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try again :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
private String tweet = "<a href=\"http://www.google.co.in\">Google</a>";
```

In place of you private String tweet

Comment: tried with this also doesnt work.. shows only Google but no link

Comment: Necessary to put "link" as i have done. Have you tried that correctly

Answer (score 0):

I have used bellow like:

1. Xml

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_welcome_message"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
       android:textSize="16sp"/>
   ```
2. In activity..

   ```
    TextView   tv_welcome_message=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_welcome_message);
    tv_welcome_message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
    String text = " <a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a>";
    tv_welcome_message.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
   ```